# reuse redundant view model code mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a master page that relies on a specific model coming from my pages.  So the ending code for basically every ViewResult ends up something like this

```
public ActionResult Details(long store_id)
{
    var store = getStore();

    var model = new ClientModel<StoreModel>(store)
        {
            UserNotifications = new UserNotificationModel(this.CurrentUser)
        };

    return View(model);
}
```

Each one of my controllers derives from a BaseController, so i was looking to put this redundant code there, but I'm not really sure the best approach to take.

The structure for my generic ClientModel is this...

```
public class ClientModel<T> : ClientModel {}

public class ClientModel {}
```

**Clarification**
The StoreModel is generic and a lot of other actions use a different view model.  I just wanted to show based on how it looks when impelmented.

Comment: Use inheritance with caution here. You might paint yourself into a corner. :)

Comment: inheritance is necessary for the MasterPage / Content Page dynamic. My master pages relies on ClientModel, and my view Pages can take can optional PageModel, the <T>.  The solution works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected ViewResult ClientModelView<T>(T model)
{
    var clientModel = new ClientModel<T>(model)
        {
            UserNotifications = new UserNotificationModel(CurrentUser)
        };

    return this.View(clientModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2134233/144496).

Basically, you create a base controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public Model GetModel() {}
}
```

Then all your controllers inherit from the base:

```
public class NewController : BaseController
{

    public ActionResult Details(long store_id)
    {

        var model = GetModel();

        return View(model);
    }

}
```

Comment: this focuses on the model, whereas i am trying to abstract the view, and allow for any type of model